# How to start hadoop on CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, hadoop

I have installed hadoop using Yum on CentOS:

```
yum install hadoop
```

Now I want to start hadoop but cannot find the `start-all.sh` script mentioned on many blogs and wiki pages such as http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop

It looks like the `start-all.sh` script was not installed by Yum, anybody have an idea why? How should I start hadoop on my system?

Comment: Did you try `service hadoop start`?

Comment: I got the following ouput "hadoop: unrecognized service" with "service hadoop start"

Comment: Sorry, worth a shot. That's the usual way you start services in Red Hat/CentOS.

Comment: What yum repository did you install hadoop from? The page you linked to documents installing hadoop a different way than you did.